# Zip is not downloading in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, zip

I use jQuery to post some data to page and download zip file using zip library in CodeIgniter, it only outputs some string data and downloading doesn't work.

[image: Output error String data]

**Code:**

```
$data = json_decode($data);
foreach ($data as $id) {
    $this->db->where('idjobs', $id);
    $this->db->where('jobs_has_clients.jobs_idjobs', $id);
    $this->db->join('status', 'status.idstatus = jobs.status_idstatus', 'left');
    $this->db->join('jobs_has_clients', 'jobs_has_clients.jobs_has_clientsSet = status.statusFor', 'left');
    $this->db->join('cv', 'cv.clients_idclients = jobs_has_clients.clients_idclients', 'left');
    $get_all_data_q = $this->db->get('jobs');
    $all_data_to_array_q = $get_all_data_q->result_array();
    $a = 0;
    foreach ($all_data_to_array_q as $zipData) {
        $path = './' . $zipData['cvFilePath'];
        $this->zip->read_file($path);
        $a++;
    }

    if ($a != 0) {
        $this->zip->download('job_' . $id . '_' . date('Y-m-d') . '_cv_archive.zip');
    }
}
```

Comment: And your code? How are we supposed to know what's wrong without seeing what you are doing.

Comment: @Alex sorry  sir. i just add code.

Comment: Are you trying to download through jquery? Don't believe you can do that.

Comment: You are probably seeing the raw zip stream because it can't be downloaded that way (could be wrong).

Comment: You should load your script from your browser, not from jQuery.

Comment: @Alex  Yes  sir. Now i  use  form  submit  for call that  page instead of jquery  post  and it work.Thanks  for your comment .

Comment: @cusmar Yes sir.I use  form  for submit. and it work. Thanks for you comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't launch a download from an Ajax query. You should load your script from your browser, not from jQuery.